# Chinese possible symbol what is it (Character identified: 亥)

Tags: translation, character-identification

[image]

Any ideas that this symbol is?

Answer (score 1):

**亥** [hài, ㄏㄞˋ]- The 12th terrestrial branch in the "Earthly Branches or Terrestrial Branches" which indicates the time 9 pm to 11 pm, or the direction in a circle, 330°.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthly_Branches

Answer (score 0):

This is a pictograph, originally designed based on the appearance of pigs, so this character also corresponds to the pig in the twelve zodiac signs. In the twelve zodiac signs, the pig runs the slowest, so it ranks last, so the 亥 character corresponds to the twelfth position of the twelve earthly branches, corresponding to 9-11 pm. However, the 亥 character also corresponds to October in the lunar calendar, because after the 亥 time corresponds to the 子 time, the 子 time is the time of extreme cold, and soon after the little spring of the October in the tenth lunar month, the coldest winter will arrive. 亥 character can also refer to a 73-year-old person. Chinese characters have a wide range of meanings. 亥 character has about 15 meanings. In short, the 亥 character means 9-11 pm at night, indicating the latest time of day, like a pig, the last animal in the twelve zodiac signs. In ancient times, the character  亥 looked like a woman on top of a man, which was like the night sky covering the sun below, approaching the extreme Yin time, also like 9-11 pm.